# I want to slowdown speed of process bar in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slidedown

1st problem-
I am trying to slow down speed of my process bar. I want it to take 1min to complete loading.Here is my code:
JS

```
  function start(al) {
     var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
     var status = document.getElementById('status');
     status.innerHTML = al + "%";
     bar.value = al;
     al++;
     var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
     if (al == 100) {
     status.innerHTML = "100%";
     bar.value = 100;
     clearTimeout(sim);
     var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
     finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
   }
```

Html code:

```
   <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:400px;"></progress>
   <span id="status"></span>
   <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
   <button onclick="start(0)">Scan</button>
```

2nd  problem-  and with loading i want some image is slidedown slowly according to my progress bar. and when process i get complete then whole image is shown on next page.

Actually i am trying to create a small website to know more as am new in this field in this website i am trying to process an image and after processing new scanned image will be shown to next page.
Help me to rectify my mistakes.

Comment: For problem 1) Increase value from 1 to n(here I increased to 100) in this line. `var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 100);`

Will it be okay to use jquery for your 2nd problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you have some syntax error in your code):

```js
 function start(al) {
     var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
     var status = document.getElementById('status');
     status.innerHTML = al + "%";
     bar.value = al;
     al++;
     
     //var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 10000);
     
     var sim = setTimeout(function() {
     
         start(al);
     }, 100); // 100 milliseconds
     
     if (al == 100) {
       status.innerHTML = "100%";
       bar.value = 100;
       clearTimeout(sim);
       var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
       finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
     }
 }
```

```html
 <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:400px;"></progress>
 <span id="status"></span>
 <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
 <button onclick="start(0)">Scan</button>
```

Try to avoid passing data to `setTimeout()` function as string. Pass anonymous function instead. It is looks like using an `eval()` function. Because It's slower to evaluate "live" code than to have the code directly in the script.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented your requirement using jquery animation. Please check below snippet and let me know if you find any query.

```js
$('#btns').click(function(){
 
  var $wrapper = $('<div />').addClass('wrap');
    
    $('img').wrap($wrapper);
    $('img').css('opacity', 1);
  
    $('img').parent().animate({
      height: '100px'
     },
     {
      duration: 2500, //you can change it according to your need of speed
     
      step: function(al) 
      {
         $('#status').html(al + "%");
         $('#progressBar').val(al);
         al++;
     
         if (al == 100) 
         {
           $('#status').html("100%");
           $('#progressBar').val(100);
         }
      },
      complete: function() 
      {
        $('#finalMessage').html("Process is complete");
      }
    });
 
 });
```

```css
img{
  opacity:0;
}

.wrap {
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:400px;"></progress>
   <span id="status"></span>
   <h1 id="finalMessage"><h1>
   <button id="btns">Scan</button> <!-- onclick="start(0)"  -->
   <img src="http://www.textileexpressfabrics.co.uk/WebRoot/BT4/Shops/BT3246/56F4/0B49/3BC3/A909/78CC/0A0C/0596/9596/tex_ex_1058_Plush_Velour_pink.jpg" />
```

Comment: I had tried to run the above code but its not running.

Comment: Have you added jquery.min.js into your html page? i.e `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`